# How to get a frame like in the image

Tags: border

[image]

I am preparing a math test. How can I get frames like in the image?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: If it appears on every page, you need a header.  Only the first page is easier.  You will probably need a graphics package like TikZ.